# Transmissão EFD Reinf - "falha no acesso ao Sistema de Procuração Eletrônica"

Tags: xml, web-service

Depois de atualizar as classes dos xsds para a versão 1.3.02, estou tentando transmitir eventos de abertura (R1000) e fechamento (R2099) do EFD Reinf. Fui corrigindo os erros conforme foram aparecendo até parar no seguinte:

> MS0020 - Ocorreu uma falha no acesso ao Sistema de Procuração
>   Eletrônica. Aguarde alguns minutos e tente novamente. (2478979111)

Não consegui progredir daí. O CNPJ nos eventos é a raiz da matriz, com oito dígitos, alinhada à direita com zeros, que de consultas ao manual e alguns fóruns foi o que eu entendi que deveria ser. O certificado é um A1 que está cadastrado no E-CAC como procurador da empresa que transmite os dados.

A mensagem parece ser um erro interno deles, mas como não vi ninguém mais falando sobre esse erro em particular imagino que seja alguma coisa no preenchimento. Seguem os xmls(hashs e assinaturas omitidos por brevidade).

Envio:

```
<Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/envioLoteEventos/v1_03_02">
<loteEventos>
    <evento id="ID1XXXXXXXXXXXXXX2018043013431200002">
        <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v1_03_02">
            <evtInfoContri id="ID1XXXXXXXXXXXXXX2018043013431200000">
                <ideEvento>
                    <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                    <procEmi>1</procEmi>
                    <verProc>1.0</verProc>
                </ideEvento>
                <ideContri>
                    <tpInsc>2</tpInsc>
                    <nrInsc>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</nrInsc>
                </ideContri>
                <infoContri>
                    <inclusao>
                        <idePeriodo>
                            <iniValid>2017-01</iniValid>
                        </idePeriodo>
                        <infoCadastro>
                            <classTrib>99</classTrib>
                            <indEscrituracao>0</indEscrituracao>
                            <indDesoneracao>0</indDesoneracao>
                            <indAcordoIsenMulta>0</indAcordoIsenMulta>
                            <indSitPJ>0</indSitPJ>
                            <contato>
                                <nmCtt>Teste</nmCtt>
                                <cpfCtt>12345678900</cpfCtt>
                                <foneFixo>2122223333</foneFixo>
                                <foneCel>21912345678</foneCel>
                                <email>teste@teste.com</email>
                            </contato>
                        </infoCadastro>
                    </inclusao>
                </infoContri>
            </evtInfoContri>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                    <Reference URI="#ID1XXXXXXXXXXXXXX2018043013431200000">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                        <DigestValue>...</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <X509Data>
                        <X509Certificate>...</X509Certificate>
                    </X509Data>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </Reinf>
    </evento>
    <evento id="ID1XXXXXXXXXXXXXX2018043013431200003">
        <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtFechamento/v1_03_02">
            <evtFechaEvPer id="ID1XXXXXXXXXXXXXX2018043013431200001">
                <ideEvento>
                    <perApur>2017-01</perApur>
                    <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                    <procEmi>1</procEmi>
                    <verProc>1</verProc>
                </ideEvento>
                <ideContri>
                    <tpInsc>2</tpInsc>
                    <nrInsc>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</nrInsc>
                </ideContri>
                <ideRespInf>
                    <nmResp>Teste</nmResp>
                    <cpfResp>12345678900</cpfResp>
                    <telefone>2122223333</telefone>
                    <email>teste@teste.com</email>
                </ideRespInf>
                <infoFech>
                    <evtServTm>N</evtServTm>
                    <evtServPr>N</evtServPr>
                    <evtAssDespRec>N</evtAssDespRec>
                    <evtAssDespRep>N</evtAssDespRep>
                    <evtComProd>N</evtComProd>
                    <evtCPRB>N</evtCPRB>
                    <evtPgtos>N</evtPgtos>
                </infoFech>
            </evtFechaEvPer>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                    <Reference URI="#ID1XXXXXXXXXXXXXX2018043013431200001">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                        <DigestValue>a17VdbLyWAEaq1ABm7pMNLI340ZlQO2b4splHna5xKA=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <X509Data>
                        <X509Certificate>...</X509Certificate>
                    </X509Data>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </Reinf>
    </evento>
</loteEventos>
```

Resposta:

```
<ReceberLoteEventosResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Body>
    <ReceberLoteEventosResult>
        <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/retornoLoteEventos/v1_03_02">
            <retornoLoteEventos id="IDB5853EC5FA5EE568D41CBEC09DD254E0">
                <ideTransmissor>
                    <IdTransmissor>16567897000170</IdTransmissor>
                </ideTransmissor>
                <status>
                    <cdStatus>0</cdStatus>
                    <descRetorno>SUCESSO</descRetorno>
                </status>
                <retornoEventos>
                    <evento id="ID1XXXXXXXXXXXXXX2018043013431200002">
                        <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtTotal/v1_03_02">
                            <evtTotal id="ID1525755225">
                                <ideEvento>
                                    <perApur />
                                </ideEvento>
                                <ideContri>
                                    <tpInsc>2</tpInsc>
                                    <nrInsc>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</nrInsc>
                                </ideContri>
                                <ideRecRetorno>
                                    <ideStatus>
                                        <cdRetorno>1</cdRetorno>
                                        <descRetorno>ERRO</descRetorno>
                                        <regOcorrs>
                                            <tpOcorr>1</tpOcorr>
                                            <localErroAviso />
                                            <codResp>MS0020</codResp>
                                            <dscResp>Ocorreu uma falha no acesso ao Sistema de Procuração Eletrônica. Aguarde alguns minutos e tente novamente. (2478979111)</dscResp>
                                        </regOcorrs>
                                    </ideStatus>
                                </ideRecRetorno>
                                <infoRecEv>
                                    <dhProcess>2018-04-30T13:43:13.8918393-03:00</dhProcess>
                                    <tpEv>1000</tpEv>
                                    <idEv>ID1XXXXXXXXXXXXXX2018043013431200000</idEv>
                                    <hash>...</hash>
                                </infoRecEv>
                                <infoTotal />
                            </evtTotal>
                            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                                <SignedInfo>
                                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                                    <Reference URI="#ID1525755225">
                                        <Transforms>
                                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                                        </Transforms>
                                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                                        <DigestValue>...</DigestValue>
                                    </Reference>
                                </SignedInfo>
                                <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
                                <KeyInfo>
                                    <X509Data>
                                        <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
                                    </X509Data>
                                </KeyInfo>
                            </Signature>
                        </Reinf>
                    </evento>
                    <evento id="ID1XXXXXXXXXXXXXX2018043013431200003">
                        <Reinf xmlns="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtTotal/v1_03_02">
                            <evtTotal id="ID1526439992">
                                <ideEvento>
                                    <perApur>2017-01</perApur>
                                </ideEvento>
                                <ideContri>
                                    <tpInsc>2</tpInsc>
                                    <nrInsc>XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</nrInsc>
                                </ideContri>
                                <ideRecRetorno>
                                    <ideStatus>
                                        <cdRetorno>1</cdRetorno>
                                        <descRetorno>ERRO</descRetorno>
                                        <regOcorrs>
                                            <tpOcorr>1</tpOcorr>
                                            <localErroAviso />
                                            <codResp>MS0020</codResp>
                                            <dscResp>Ocorreu uma falha no acesso ao Sistema de Procuração Eletrônica. Aguarde alguns minutos e tente novamente. (2478979111)</dscResp>
                                        </regOcorrs>
                                    </ideStatus>
                                </ideRecRetorno>
                                <infoRecEv>
                                    <dhProcess>2018-04-30T13:43:13.9543704-03:00</dhProcess>
                                    <tpEv>2099</tpEv>
                                    <idEv>ID1XXXXXXXXXXXXXX2018043013431200001</idEv>
                                    <hash>...=</hash>
                                </infoRecEv>
                                <infoTotal />
                            </evtTotal>
                            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                                <SignedInfo>
                                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                                    <Reference URI="#ID1526439992">
                                        <Transforms>
                                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                                        </Transforms>
                                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                                        <DigestValue>...</DigestValue>
                                    </Reference>
                                </SignedInfo>
                                <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
                                <KeyInfo>
                                    <X509Data>
                                        <X509Certificate>...</X509Certificate>
                                    </X509Data>
                                </KeyInfo>
                            </Signature>
                        </Reinf>
                    </evento>
                </retornoEventos>
            </retornoLoteEventos>
        </Reinf>
    </ReceberLoteEventosResult>
</Body>
```

Se alguém tiver alguma ideia agradeço muito!

Comment: Pela mensagem parece ser uma instabilidade interna mesmo, da ligação com o sistema de procuração eletrônica. Você não consegue fazer um teste com outro contribuinte que você tenha o certificado digital, para tirar a prova? Se o erro estiver só no uso da procuração eletrônica, manda uma mensagem no Fale Conosco: https://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/contato/fale-conosco/empresa/sped/efd-reinf-1

Comment: De qualquer forma, eu não aconselharia enviar o R-1000 e o R-2099 juntos, já que não há controle sobre a ordem de processamento, e dessa forma o R-2099 pode ser processado antes do R-1000, ou seja, antes mesmo de haver o contribuinte. Então envie o R-1000, receba a resposta, se for positiva, envie o R-2099.

Comment: Vou tentar transmitir como outro CNPJ e retorno. O R1000 e o R2099 estavam juntos por razões de teste também, mas é bom saber. Sabe se, dentro de um evento tem-se garantia de que as informações e, portanto, os erros são processados em ordem?

Comment: @PedroGaspar testei com outro contribuinte e o erro foi mesmo.

Comment: Sim, o evento é processado todo de uma vez. Mas esse outro contribuinte que você testou você tem o certificado digital ou é procuração também? Tem que ser um que você tenha acesso ao  certificado digital diretamente, sem ser procuração.

Comment: É um que eu tenho acesso direto ao certificado. EDIT: e o erro continua o mesmo, mesmo não precisando de procuração.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está na tag `tpInsc`, preenchida como `<tpInsc>2</tpInsc>`, relativo ao preenchimento para pessoa física, ao invés de `<tpInsc>1</tpInsc>` para pessoa jurídica. Trocando isso o problema foi resolvido.